# how to implement a many to many relationship in objectify v3?

Tags: google-app-engine, many-to-many, objectify

according to the documentation the model should be like this

```
public class Employee
{
  @Id String name;
  Key<Employee>[] subordinates;
}
```

I need to know how can I add subordinates to an Employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would probably be for each `Subordinate` entity, to have a property with its manager, like this:

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    String name;

    Key<Employee> manager;
}
```

In any case, if you still want to have a list of subordinates in each `Employee` entity, first you get the entity, you add the `Key` of the subordinate to the list, and you save the entity.

Hope this helps.